# javaScript form validation with multiple forms

Tags: javascript, validation

I have two forms on different pages of my website, however I want to re-use the javaScript validation. So for example:

```
   function notnull() {
   var firstName = document.forms["newsletter"]["firstName"].value;
   if (firstName === null || firstName === "") {
       inlineMsg('firstName', 'You must enter your name.', 3000000);      
       return false;
   } else {
       return true;
   }
}
```

This code is only good for my newsletter form (e.g. document.forms["newsletter"]["firstName"].value) but I want to use it for my "contact" form too.

Can I build the variables up dynamically like document.forms[][].value?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your notnull function to accept 2 parameters

```
function notnull(formType,fieldName){
   var fieldName = document.forms[formType][fieldName].value;
   if(fieldName === null || fieldName === "") {
      inlineMsg(fieldName, 'You must enter your '+fieldName,3000000);
      return false;
   } else
      return true;
}
```

something along that line. I'm unsure what your inlineMsg does. You can also alternatively pass in the error friendly name for your error message into the function.

I'm sure there are better approach of handling the above, but looking at your code only, that's what I would suggest.